# bash: a simple FIFO (first-in first-out) queue

Tags: bash, fifo

I am looking for a portable bash solution for a simple FIFO queue. My queue input will always be a single line of text.I came up with a  simple solution, which works well.

```
fifo_queue="fifo.txt";
fifo_tmp="fifo.tmp"

# put a new line into FIFO
echo "append to FIFO a line" >> $fifo_stack;

#get line back from FIFO
echo $(head -n1 "$fifo_queue")
tail -n +2 "$fifo_queue" > "$fifo_tmp" && mv "$fifo_tmp" "$fifo_queue"
```

Now the question: Is there a more elegant (i.e. easy understandable) way to retrieve the FIFO line. For example with a simple one-liner instead of two lines?

Comment: "popping" a stack is inherently a two-step algorithm: get first element, and remove it. You did good to implement it in 2 lines. You can put them inside a function to hide it away.

Comment: nag ... a queue is a FIFO ... a stack is a LIFO (last-in, first-out)

Comment: do you need this construct to persist across script calls, or perhaps between parallel calls, hence the use of a file? or does the construct only need to persist for the life of a single script call?

Comment: If you know the maximum number of lines you'd store at a time, just use an array and rotate.

Comment: Using a file for this is fairly questionable: unless you get quite fancy, you end up rewriting the whole thing from scratch whenever you need to make any modification. If the queue can be large, you're probably better off with a directory instead of a single file, so you can just create a new file with a n+1 name or read the file with the lowest name. (There are also approaches that require storing a byte offset and seeking to that offset with a tool like `dd`; you've got the startup time for that tool itself to pay, but it avoids needing to rewrite all the data when popping off the beginning)

Comment: (mind, "read the file with the lowest name" can _itself_ be an operation that doesn't scale well as the queue gets large)

Comment: Anyhow -- if this is something being constructed for serious use, you've got bigger concerns to deal with than just readability; but without the question specifying the use case, we can't really speak to suitability-to-purpose.

Comment: (Another reason to avoid modifying content in-place is that it provides more opportunities for data corruption; if you create a separate file for each item as it's enqueued and delete that file when the item is dequeued without ever editing it between, there's less chance of an interrupted operation or bug destroying the data)

Comment: Also, there's no reason to `echo $(head ...)`; just run `head ...` without the `echo $()` surrounding it; among other things, you get less bugs that way (you don't want an enqueued `*` to be replaced with a list of files in the current directory).

Comment: @Charles, thanks for all your valuable comments, you are right, that using a directory would be more reliable.

Comment: @markp-fuso : I updated the question from stack to queue, thanks

Comment: Some further update describing desired performance characteristics would still be helpful. Is it okay if popping something off takes time that scales with the amount of data in the queue (as it does if you're rewriting the file with a tool like sed), or is it desired that operations take constant time? (If a queue will only ever be tiny, maybe the work for constant-time operation isn't worth it)

Comment: @MarcelSonderegger One important interrogation is: From where do you add new content to the file and from where do you "consume" the data. If those two actions are done asynchronously then you'll have to implement a locking mechanism.

Comment: @Fravadona: I agree about the locking mechanism, but this is not necessary in my case. In this case I would prefer Charles Duffy solution using files in a directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to edit a file, use an editor; don't cobble something together with `tail`.

```
put () {
    printf '%s\n' "$1" >> "$2"
}

get () {   
    printf '1p\n1d\nwq\n' | ed -s "$1"
}
```

Then

```
$ put a queue.txt
$ put b queue.txt
$ get queue.txt
a
$ put c queue.txt
$ get queue.txt
b
```

Comment: Nice clean solution, even if it has all the drawbacks described in this thread.

Answer (score 3):

One option for retrieving the next FIFO line is to use the POSIX standard [ed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html) utility:

```
printf '%s\n' 1p 1d w | ed -s -- "$fifo_stack"
```

This invokes `ed` on the FIFO file and issues 3 commands to it.  `1p` prints the first line.  `1d` deletes the first line.  `w` saves the change back to the file.

You may run into problems with this approach if the FIFO file is very large, but you should be OK up to tens of megabytes on a modern machine.

Answer (score 2):

For a fifo stack, the modified version of your logic would be something like the below script.  Naturally, you would need to modify that to allow passing the desired line as a parameter on the command line (or as redirected input).

As **for removing the first/last line from the stack/buffer** file from the file **in-place**, that would be a task for **sed**.

I was able to identify the logic for deleting the first/last line depending on fifo/lifo mode using very simple sed directives.  That is implemented in the below script.

```
#!/bin/bash

Push=0
Pop=0
fifo=1 ; mode="fifo"    ### DEFAULT
lifo=0

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
        --push ) Push=1 ; Pop=0 ; shift ;;
        --pop ) Pop=1 ; Push=0 ; shift ;;
        --fifo ) fifo=1 ; lifo=0 ; mode="fifo" ; shift ;;   ### Buffer MODE
        --lifo ) lifo=1 ; fifo=0 ; mode="lifo" ; shift ;;   ### Stack MODE
        * ) echo -e "\n Invalid parameter used on command line.  Only valid options: [ --push | --pop ]\n Bye!\n" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

if [ ${Push} -eq 0 -a ${Pop} -eq 0 ]
then
    echo -e "\n ERROR: must specify one of the two stack operations: --push or --pop \n Bye!\n" ; exit 1
fi

stack="${mode}.txt";
tmp="${mode}.tmp"
if [ ! -f "${stack}" ] ; then touch "${stack}" ; fi

i=$(( $(wc -l "${stack}" | awk '{ print $1 }' ) + 1 ))

if [ ${Push} -eq 1 ]
then
    # put a new line into FIFO/LIFO
    echo "append to FIFO - line ${i}" >> "${stack}"
    wc -l "${stack}"
fi

if [ ${Pop} -eq 1 ]
then
    if [ -s "${stack}" ]
    then
        #get line back from FIFO
        if [ ${fifo} -eq 1 ]
        then
            head -n1 "${stack}"
            sed --in-place '1d' "${stack}"
            wc -l "${stack}"
        else
            tail -n1 "${stack}"
            sed --in-place '$d' "${stack}"
            wc -l "${stack}"
        fi
    else
        echo -e "\t ERROR: attempt to pop line from EMPTY stack.\n" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

Session log is as follows:

```
me@OasisMega1:/0__WORK$ ./test_129.sh --push -fifo
1 fifo.txt
me@OasisMega1:/0__WORK$ ./test_129.sh --push -fifo
2 fifo.txt
me@OasisMega1:/0__WORK$ ./test_129.sh --push -fifo
3 fifo.txt
me@OasisMega1:/0__WORK$ ./test_129.sh --push -fifo
4 fifo.txt
me@OasisMega1:/0__WORK$ ./test_129.sh --pop -fifo
append to FIFO - line 1
3 fifo.txt
me@OasisMega1:/0__WORK$ ./test_129.sh --pop -fifo
append to FIFO - line 2
2 fifo.txt
me@OasisMega1:/0__WORK$ ./test_129.sh --pop -fifo
append to FIFO - line 3
1 fifo.txt
me@OasisMega1:/0__WORK$ ./test_129.sh --pop -fifo
append to FIFO - line 4
0 fifo.txt
me@OasisMega1:/0__WORK$ ./test_129.sh --pop -fifo
     ERROR: attempt to pop line from EMPTY stack.
me@OasisMega1:/0__WORK$
```

Session log for LIFO mode is as follows:

```
me@OasisMega1:0__WORK$ ./test_129.sh --push --lifo
1 lifo.txt
me@OasisMega1:0__WORK$ ./test_129.sh --push --lifo
2 lifo.txt
me@OasisMega1:0__WORK$ ./test_129.sh --push --lifo
3 lifo.txt
me@OasisMega1:0__WORK$ ./test_129.sh --push --lifo
4 lifo.txt
me@OasisMega1:0__WORK$ ./test_129.sh --pop --lifo
append to FIFO - line 4
3 lifo.txt
me@OasisMega1:0__WORK$ ./test_129.sh --pop --lifo
append to FIFO - line 3
2 lifo.txt
me@OasisMega1:0__WORK$ ./test_129.sh --pop --lifo
append to FIFO - line 2
1 lifo.txt
me@OasisMega1:0__WORK$ ./test_129.sh --pop --lifo
append to FIFO - line 1
0 lifo.txt
me@OasisMega1:0__WORK$ ./test_129.sh --pop --lifo
     ERROR: attempt to pop line from EMPTY stack.

me@OasisMega1:0__WORK$
```

This version of the script incorporates providing input for buffer/stack on command line, and option for display of current buffer/stack contents.  Also provides return code which might be used for decision on whether contents requiring "processing" are still in buffer or not.

```
#!/bin/bash
    
Push=0
Pop=0
Display=0
fifo=1 ; mode="FIFO"    ### DEFAULT
lifo=0
dataline=""

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
        --push ) Push=1 ; Pop=0 ; shift ;;
        --pop ) Pop=1 ; Push=0 ; shift ;;
        --show ) Push=0; Pop=0 ; Display=1 ; shift ;;
        --fifo ) fifo=1 ; lifo=0 ; mode="FIFO" ; shift ;;   ### Buffer MODE
        --lifo ) lifo=1 ; fifo=0 ; mode="LIFO" ; shift ;;   ### Stack MODE
        -- ) shift ; dataline=${@} ; break ;;
        * ) echo -e "\n Invalid parameter used on command line.  Only valid options: [ --push | --pop ]\n Bye!\n" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

if [ ${Display} -eq 1 ]
then
    if [ ${fifo} -eq 1 ]
    then
        if [ -f FIFO.txt ]
        then
            if [ -s FIFO.txt ]
            then
                wc -l FIFO.txt >&2
                echo -e "Hit return to view contents ...\c" >&2 ; read k <&2
                more FIFO.txt
                RC=98
            else
                echo -e "\n FIFO buffer is empty at this time.\n" >&2
                RC=0
            fi
        else
            echo -e "\n FIFO buffer does not exist.\n" >&2
            RC=99
        fi
    fi
    if [ ${lifo} -eq 1 ]
    then
        if [ -f LIFO.txt ]
        then
            if [ -s LIFO.txt ]
            then
                wc -l LIFO.txt >&2
                echo -e "Hit return to view contents ...\c" >&2 ; read k <&2
                more LIFO.txt
                RC=98
            else
                echo -e "\n LIFO buffer is empty at this time.\n" >&2
                RC=0
            fi
        else
            echo -e "\n LIFO buffer does not exist.\n" >&2
            RC=99
        fi
    fi
    exit ${RC}
fi

if [ ${Push} -eq 1 -a -z "${dataline}" ]
then
    echo -e "\n ERROR: did not provide data for capture in BUFFER/STACK\n Bye!\n" ; exit 1
fi

if [ ${Push} -eq 0 -a ${Pop} -eq 0 ]
then
    echo -e "\n ERROR: must specify one of the two stack operations: --push or --pop \n Bye!\n" >&2 ; exit 1
fi

stack="${mode}.txt";
tmp="${mode}.tmp"
if [ ! -f "${stack}" ] ; then touch "${stack}" ; fi

if [ ${Push} -eq 1 ]
then
    # put a new line into FIFO/LIFO
    echo "${dataline}" >> "${stack}"
    wc -l "${stack}" >&2
fi

if [ ${Pop} -eq 1 ]
then
    if [ -s "${stack}" ]
    then
        #get line back from FIFO
        if [ ${fifo} -eq 1 ]
        then
            head -n1 "${stack}"
            sed --in-place '1d' "${stack}"
            wc -l "${stack}" >&2
        else
            tail -n1 "${stack}"
            sed --in-place '$d' "${stack}"
            wc -l "${stack}" >&2
        fi
    else
        echo -e "\t ERROR: attempt to pop line from EMPTY stack.\n" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use a real fifo. Example

```
#!/bin/bash

#--- setup
FIFO="fifo.tmp"
rm -f "$FIFO"
mkfifo "$FIFO"

#--- sending data in background
for (( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )); do echo $i; sleep 1; done >"$FIFO" &

#--- receiving data
echo "start"
while read line
do
    echo "> $line"
done < "$FIFO"
echo "stop"

#--- clean
rm -f "$FIFO"
```

Answer (score 2):

A directory-based version with simple usage, error handling for common problems, and O(1) performance characteristics (meaning it doesn't get slower as the queue gets longer):

```console
$ source fifo-utils.bash # assuming this file has the below code
$ get fifo.d
ERROR: fifo directory 'fifo.d' not initialized
$ put fifo.d 13
$ get fifo.d
13
$ get fifo.d
ERROR: fifo directory 'fifo.d' is empty
$ put fifo.d fourteen
$ put fifo.d fifteen
$ get fifo.d
fourteen
$ get fifo.d
fifteen
$ get fifo.d
ERROR: fifo directory 'fifo.d' is empty
```

Implementation (be sure to note the "future enhancements" list):

```
# Format:
# "head" contains the name of the next item ready for read
# "tail" contains the next place where newly-added data would be written
#
# If "head" matches "tail", the FIFO is empty.
#
# Possible future enhancements:
# - Use create-and-rename pattern to update counters atomically
# - If head or tail is unexpectedly empty, but numbered files exist, recover from
#   highest/lowest numbered file
# - Lock head and tail files with flock to make concurrent use safe
# - Add "get" support for blocking if queue is empty (can do this by using inotifywait
#   to block until tail is updated before proceeding should head == tail)

get() {
  local fifo_dir=$1 head tail
  [[ -s $fifo_dir/head && -e $fifo_dir/tail ]] || {
    echo "ERROR: fifo directory ${fifo_dir@Q} not initialized" >&2
    return 1
  }
  head=$(<"$fifo_dir/head") || return
  tail=$(<"$fifo_dir/tail") || return
  (( head >= tail )) && {
    echo "ERROR: fifo directory ${fifo_dir@Q} is empty" >&2
    return 2
  }
  [[ -e "$fifo_dir/$head" ]] || {
    echo "ERROR: fifo directory ${fifo_dir@Q} has head at $head, but data does not exist" >&2
  }
  cat -- "$fifo_dir/$head" || return
  printf '%s\n' "$(( head + 1 ))" >"$fifo_dir/head" || return
}

put() {
  local fifo_dir=$1 data=$2 head tail
  [[ -d $fifo_dir ]] || { mkdir -p -- "$fifo_dir" || exit; }
  [[ -s "$fifo_dir/head" ]] || { echo 0 >"$fifo_dir/head" || return; }
  [[ -s "$fifo_dir/tail" ]] || { echo 0 >"$fifo_dir/tail" || return; }
  head=$(<"$fifo_dir/head") || return
  tail=$(<"$fifo_dir/tail") || return
  printf '%s\n' "$data" >"$fifo_dir/$tail" || return
  echo "$(( tail + 1 ))" >"$fifo_dir/tail" || return
}
```

Comment: Clean implementation, thank you.  For the application right now it would be an overshoot, but maybe it serves somebody else.